# Calling the service class from the active job class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, jobs, sidekiq

I have my rails controller class which calls my active job class

```
class Api::V2::Events::WegSessionsController < Api::V2::Events::ApplicationController
before_action :load_service

.... some code

def synchronize
@service.keep_cancelled = params[:keep_cancelled].to_b
if @service.valid_connection?

  WegJob.perform_later

  render json: {
    status: :ok,
    message: @service.message
  }, status: :ok
else
  render json: {
    status: :unprocessable_entity,
    errors: @event.errors.full_messages
  }, status: :ok
end
end

... some code

def load_service
  @service = WegService.new(event: @event)
end
end
```

I have configured my job class in my Rails project to use Sidekiq and calling the service method here

```
class WegJob < ApplicationJob
queue_as :default

def perform(*args)
 WegService.synchronize
end
end
```

This service class has the implementation of 'synchronize' method which I would be calling from my job class

```
class WegService
 include ActiveModel::Model

... some code

def synchronize
 if event.weg_synced_at.present?
  update
 else
  create
 end

 event.update(weg_synced_at: Time.current)
end

... some code along with update and create method implementations.
end
```

When I am doing this, I am getting the following error

```
[ActiveJob] [WegJob] [fd7c1869-6909-471c-bf32-9b2270a8c39c] Error performing 
WegJob (Job ID: fd7c1869-6909-471c-bf32-9b2270a8c39c) from Async(default) in 
2556.3ms: NoMethodError (undefined method `synchronize' for WegService:Class):
```

I know my way calling the service method from the Job class is wrong. Where could I have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're defining a instance method in WegService:

```
class WegService
 include ActiveModel::Model

... some code

def synchronize
 if event.weg_synced_at.present?
  update
 else
  create
 end

 event.update(weg_synced_at: Time.current)
end

... some code along with update and create method implementations.
end
```

Yet you're calling it as if it was a class method:

```
class WegJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    WegService.synchronize
  end
end
```

Of course it does not work. Either redefine the method as a class method or create a factory method:

```
class WegService
  include ActiveModel::Model

  #.. some code

  def synchronize
    if event.weg_synced_at.present?
      update
    else
      create
    end

    event.update(weg_synced_at: Time.current)
  end

  def self.syncronize
    WegService.new.synchronize
  end
  # ... some code along with update and create method implementations.
end
```

But its an extremely questionable design for a service object. The name is far to vague and service objects really only should have a call method. `include ActiveModel::Model` also tells me that what your creating is really just a model.

Comment: Is there a way I can pass the object instance(@service) of my service class from the controller to my Job class so that I can still call the 'synchronize' method as an instance method?